# Output Caching in ASP.NET Web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am trying to disable or set the minimal caching of web pages of my ASP.NET Web App on User Browsers. So, I added the following lines in web.config.

```
    <system.web>        
    <caching>
          <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
              <add name="Cache30Seconds" duration="30" 
                varyByParam="none" />
            </outputCacheProfiles>
          </outputCacheSettings>
        </caching>
    </system.web>
```

Now I try to use this profile like this msdn document says here
If we need to use this in any page, we need to use `<%@ OutputCache CacheProfile="Cache30Seconds" Duration="30" %>`

Now, this raised me the following questions.
1. If we need to use it on everypage, why are we specifying these settings in web.config file?
2. Do we need to define duration both in page and in Cache profile in Web.config? if so, why and can we use different durations for both of them?

If we are using master page we can define this OutputCache directive there to prevent any content page caching. But, I am curious to know why we need to define in two places instead of one ?

Answer (score -1):

The OutputCache directive wont really affect user's browsers.  You want to add a cache-control header to your responses.

OutputCache will tell IIS to store your dynamic content rather than regenerating it for the configured period of time.  A cache-control header will tell a browser that it needs to pull a new version of your content after the max-age time has expired.

http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: Interesting, then using this in my web app is waste as it doesn't solve my purpose of preventing user browser caching. Then the name OutputCache is misleading, it should be something ServerOutputCache.However, Can we add Cache-control headers for our webapp from Web.config? That being said, my two questions are still unanswered. Any insigts into them?

Comment: I tried adding this to web.config too but still pages are cached as user experiencing as user needs to clear cache to see newly added content on Server.`<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
        <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
        <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: Have you verified that the cache-control header is being sent in the response?  You should be able to get away with just a no-cache value.

Also, this should help you get them configured correctly: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Comment: Yes, it is as follows`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 292561
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
` Allowing Only Browser to cache . Except the original request, all the associated resources such as images etc.. are loaded form Cache.

Comment: Sorry for the redundant question - but you say the browser is caching images and other resources are being cached.  Is the cache-control header being sent with the responses for those requests as well?  The cache-control header will only work on the specific piece of content that it's set on - that is to say, if you have two files, and the cache-control header is only sent with one of the files, the browser will still cache the second piece of content.  You should be able to configure the cache-control header at the site level so all responses from that site include it.

Comment: I see no cache-control header for the cached resources. So, like you said it means they were being cached and loaded from there. "You should be able to configure the cache-control header at the site level so all responses from that site include it." Thats what I wanna do and included the httpprotocol tag in my web.config as I said in my previous comment. But somehow only Page is being reloaded and associated resources are cached. Does this mean, if Page is changed, it will be loaded immediately for user but not the associated resources?

Comment: Correct, the page with the cache-control header should always be refreshed from the server.  Just be sure to remember that if you still have the OutputCache directive defined in your web.config, it may make it appear that your content is stale.  The browser will go to the server, and the server will serve its own cached content :)

Comment: So, What's the way to fix the caching for the Site Level? Am I doing it right by including before mentioned settings of Httpprotocol in Web.config? or Is there something different we need to do.I need to disable caching for the entire Web Application. I am back to square 1...:(

Comment: This link should explain everything: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Comment: Oh my gosh - I just realized I had a brain fart in the comment where I explained the cache control header to you.  If you have two files and the cache-control header is only sent with one piece of content, the browser will only cache the content that was sent with a cache-control header.  Sorry :(